# Usings abstract class to add a method to an interface

Tags: java

I want to add a method to an interface, but i do not want to rewrite all the implementations (i only need to use it in one or two implementation). I read that i can achive this with the use abstract classes, but i cant quite figure out how its done?

Inteface:

```
public interface Animal {
    public void doSound();
}
```

Classes:

```
public class Cat implements Animal {

    @Override
    public void doSound() {
        System.out.print("meow");
    }

}


public class Dog implements Animal{

    @Override
    public void doSound() {
        System.out.print("bark");
    }

}
```

What i want is to be able to call

```
animal.doSomethingElse()
```

but i dont want to add this method to every implementation. Can this be done?

EDIT:
Should have mentioned this before, i am not using java 8.

Comment: SImple. add `doSomethingElse()` to `Animal` class. You can access it in `Cat` as well as `Dog` :) . BTW you need to make `Animal` *abstract*.

Comment: @TheLostMind Animal is interface and as OP said "...but I do not want to rewrite all the implementations". Probably default methods can help in this case.

Comment: possible in [java 8](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) interfaces. prior to that, just make Animal an abstract class

Comment: @Pshemo - Yes. `Animal` needs to be *abstract*.

Answer (score 3):

You could change `Animal` into an abstract class. This will enable you to selectively implement methods:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    public abstract void doSound();

    public void doSomethingElse() {
    }
}
```

Comment: But that still means i have to change all the implementations? At least replace implements with extends?

Comment: @user1985273: Yes you do have to change `implements` to `extends` (I didn't realise you were including this in "changing all the implementations").

Comment: So there is actually no advantage in changing the interface to an abstract class - both ways i have to edit the implementations. Just in one way i have to change implements with extends and in other case i have to add an empty implementation of the method i add to an interface?

Answer (score 3):

It is possible in Java 8 with help of default method in interface.

```
public interface Animal {
    void doSound();

    default void doSomethingElse(){
      // do something
    }
}
```

In case of default methods, your implemented classes from Animal doesn't have to override them.

prior to java 8, you have to make your Animal class abstract and add method implementation there.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no: you cannot add a method to an interface without having to recompile all implementations of the interface.

You can add a method to the abstract class, and change all references to the interface with references to your abstract class. That, however, defeats the purpose of having the interface in the first place.

Finally, in Java 8 you can address this problem by providing a default implementation of a method in an interface. If Java 8 is an option, I would definitely recommend this route.

If you would like to avoid problems like this in the future, you could follow the interface + adapter pattern that Java designers have been following in the AWT framewrok (among other places). They would provide a pair of an interface and its default, do-nothing implementation. Everyone would be encouraged to program to the interface, and base their implementations of the interface on its default implementation counterpart (the adapter). This way Swing designers were free to add more methods to their interface without breaking existing implementations.

For reference, see [`MouseListener` interface](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseListener.html) and [`MouseAdapter` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/event/MouseAdapter.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible with Java including versions to 7. 
You can define interface Animal as abstract class and implement new method within it. Sample code as follows:

```
public abstract class Animal {

    public abstract void doSound();

    public void doSomethingElse() {}

}
```

However if you are using Java 8 you have mechanism which is called default methods. Example below

```
public interface Sample {

    public abstract void doSound();

    public default void doSomethingElse() {};

}
```

default methods do not have to be implemented by classes. Mechanism is very useful when it comes to interfaces with large number of classes implementing certain interface. You can extend it without changing all classes

Answer (score 0):

You can extend Animal as a separate interface or an abstract class.

```
public interface Pet extends Animal {
    public void fetch();
}
```

or

```
public abstract class Pet implements Animal {
    public abstract void fetch();
}
```